# What is the customary way of sharing a code snippet to illustrate a reported bug on GitHub?

Tags: github, bug-report

I reported a bug on GitHub, now I'm asked for files, but there's no way to attach them to the raised issue (e.g. on Launchpad you can attach file to a bug report, but on GitHub there's only option to attach pictures).

I've read the issues section of the GitHub FAQ, but didn't find anything sufficiently illuminating. It seems like a novice user is implicitly directed by the site somewhere, but where?

Should I just create a repository and put all the requested snippets and output files there? Or should I just email the files to the project's maintainer? What I'm asking here boils down to this: what people do usually?

Comment: What project are you talking about, and what kind of bug? Please edit your question, by giving such details, to improve it!

Comment: Well, I'm asking a general question because I'm looking for a general answer. I'd really like to know what's the customary, always-applicable, not dependent on the project or the bug filed method to do this (or - now I have to wonder - if there is any). Just like with my example - on Launchpad you just attach relevant files to the post that reports a bug. No matter the bug or other circumstances - it's the customary and intended way to do this. Am I really to think GitHub doesn't facilitate in any way such a basic need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are pointing to specific lines in the code base, you can use [line links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23821267) to deep-link into the code. (You should pick a specific commit and not just point to master as those links might become outdated if the code changes.)

If you just want to put up some sample code that you created, that is a perfect use for [Github Gists](https://gist.github.com). These can even be cloned and updated like a regular repo, but are much more lightweight.

If you have code that can be demonstrated in a browser, use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar to create something people can see and interact with.

**Bonus**: If you are trying to demonstrate performance issues in JavaScript, you can use [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) to write an example test.

Comment: Gists! OK, you mean like this? https://gist.github.com/ThreefoldBurly/2760f67f97399e0cec6c

Comment: Looks good! Now you can just link to it from a comment in the issue it references.

Comment: Marked it as accepted as it answers the main question as phrased in the title of my post, but wouldn't mind some advice on what to do if asked for some additional files by the project's maintainer. Send them over email or is there some better, github way of accomplishing that?

Comment: You can update the gist by cloning and pushing the changes up. What's nice about that is that the conversation continues in public, which may help others in the future. On th other hand, the project owner may prefer another method. Once they respond, they may tell you what to do. If they don't say, just ask. There's never any harm in that.

Answer (score 0):

Many projects hosted on `github` have some infrastructure for testing, i.e. some input files and expected output (e.g. fish-shell has a [tests/](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/tree/master/tests) directory) You could patch the software (i.e. fork it then make a pull request) to add an additional test case illustrating the bug.

You should also contact some of the main authors, they probably will be happy to get a bug report .... And you could report some issue (see [this example](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues))

At last, if you find a bug and are able to correct it, you fork the repo, patch it, and make a pull request.

Comment: What I'm asking is what to do after I reported an issue. Let's say I'm testing a library used to generate some files. If I raise an issue reporting some problems with it, probably I'm gonna be asked for the files generated as well as the code that generated them. From your answer I now assume I'm supposed to put the code straight in the body of the comment under the raised issue, right? What with the files?

Comment: I think you should contact the authors and ask them what is appropriate for the particular project.